identify Macro Camera in android smartphone using kotlin/java
I am trying to programmatically check whether the Android Smartphone has the macro camera or not.
Tried CameraManager and through that found the different characteristics of the camera. Than found the specific thresholds of the macro camera and placed the conditions on the characteristics to find the availability of the macro camera in the android smartphone. As there is not direct way as far as I searched to find the macro camera.
val cameraManager =  context?.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as? CameraManager

        cameraManager?.cameraIdList?.forEach { cameraId ->
            val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
            val lensFacing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
            val capabilities =
                characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)
            capabilities?.let {
                Log.d("macroCameraLog_2", "isMacroCameraSupported: CAMERA_ID $cameraId")
                Log.d("macroCameraLog_2", "isMacroCameraSupported: HARD_WARE_LEVEL $it")
                if (it >= CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_3) {
                    Log.d("macroCameraLog_2", "isMacroCameraSupported: TRUE")
                }
            }

        val afModes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AF_AVAILABLE_MODES)
            afModes?.let { modes ->
                Log.d("macroCameraLog_3", "isMacroCameraSupported: CAMERA_ID $cameraId")
                Log.d(
                    "macroCameraLog_3",
                    "isMacroCameraSupported: MODES ${formatCharacteristicValue(modes)}"
                )
                if (modes.contains(CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_MACRO)) {
                    Log.d("macroCameraLog_3", "Macro AF mode is supported")
                }

                if (modes.contains(CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                    Log.d("macroCameraLog_3", "CONTROL_Macro AF mode is supported")
                }
            }

            if (lensFacing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
                // Get the minimum focus distance
                val minFocusDistance =
                    characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE)
                        ?: return false
                Log.d(
                    "macroCameraLog",
                    "isMacroCameraSupported: Min_Focus -> $minFocusDistance"
                )
                Log.d("macroCameraLog", "isMacroCameraSupported: Camera_ID -> $cameraId")
                // Define a threshold for macro capability (e.g., less than or equal to 0.05 meters or 5 cm)
                if (minFocusDistance in 0.01..0.05) {
                    Log.d(
                        "macroCameraLog",
                        "isMacroCameraSupported: Min_Focus -> $minFocusDistance"
                    )
                    Log.d("macroCameraLog", "isMacroCameraSupported: Camera_ID -> $cameraId")
                }
            }
            // Check if it's a rear camera
            if (lensFacing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
                // Check for physical cameras in a multi-camera system
                val physicalCameraIds = characteristics.physicalCameraIds
                if (physicalCameraIds.isNotEmpty()) {
                    for (physicalCameraId in physicalCameraIds) {
                        val physicalCharacteristics =
                            cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(physicalCameraId)
                        val physicalFocalLengths =
                            physicalCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)

                        val minFocusDistance =
                            physicalCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE)
                                ?: return false

                        // Define a threshold for macro capability (e.g., less than or equal to 0.05 meters or 5 cm)
                        Log.d(
                            "macroCameraLog",
                            "Physical_isMacroCameraSupported: Camera_ID -> $cameraId"
                        )
                        Log.d(
                            "macroCameraLog",
                            "Physical_isMacroCameraSupported: Min_Focus -> $minFocusDistance"
                        )
                        if (minFocusDistance in 0.01..0.05) {
                            Log.d(
                                "macroCameraLog",
                                "Physical_isMacroCameraSupported: Min_Focus -> $minFocusDistance"
                            )
                            Log.d(
                                "macroCameraLog",
                                "Physical_isMacroCameraSupported: Camera_ID -> $cameraId"
                            )
                        }

                        physicalFocalLengths?.let { focalLengths ->
                            for (focalLength in focalLengths) {
                                // Check for macro lens characteristics
                                if (focalLength in 1.0..2.0) {
                                    // Macro lens found in a multi-camera system
                                    // return true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

The only possible solution I came up with the various properties of the macro camera to be checked according to the specific thresholds like the focal length, hardware level, minimum focus distance and autofocus mode. But I didn't found any solid solution for checking that the device have the macro camera or not.

You're on the right path by checking various camera characteristics like focal length, autofocus modes, hardware level, and minimum focus distance to determine whether a device has a macro camera. Since Android does not provide a direct API for identifying a macro camera, using these parameters is the best approach. However, there are a few ways to refine your detection mechanism for macro cameras
fun isMacroCameraSupported(context: Context): Boolean {
    val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager

    cameraManager.cameraIdList.forEach { cameraId ->
        val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)

        
        val lensFacing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
        if (lensFacing != CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
            return@forEach 
        }

       
        val afModes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AF_AVAILABLE_MODES)
        if (afModes != null && afModes.contains(CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_MACRO)) {
            Log.d("macroCameraLog", "Macro AF mode is supported for camera ID $cameraId")
        }

       
        val minFocusDistance = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE)
        if (minFocusDistance != null && minFocusDistance in 0.01..0.05) {
            Log.d("macroCameraLog", "Macro capability found based on focus distance for camera ID $cameraId")
        }

       
        val focalLengths = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)
        focalLengths?.let {
            for (focalLength in focalLengths) {
                if (focalLength in 1.0..2.0) {
                    Log.d("macroCameraLog", "Macro lens found based on focal length for camera ID $cameraId")
                    return true // A macro camera is detected
                }
            }
        }

       
        val hardwareLevel = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)
        if (hardwareLevel != null && hardwareLevel >= CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_3) {
            Log.d("macroCameraLog", "High-end camera hardware detected for camera ID $cameraId")
        }

       
        val physicalCameraIds = characteristics.physicalCameraIds
        if (physicalCameraIds.isNotEmpty()) {
            physicalCameraIds.forEach { physicalCameraId ->
                val physicalCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(physicalCameraId)
                val physicalFocalLengths = physicalCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)
                physicalFocalLengths?.forEach { focalLength ->
                    if (focalLength in 1.0..2.0) {
                        Log.d("macroCameraLog", "Macro lens detected in multi-camera system for physical camera ID $physicalCameraId")
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false // if false -> No macro camera found
}

maybe try this

Well checking various camera characteristics and returning the status, sometimes return true for the devices having not the macro camera, because any of the camera in that smartphone meets the condition.
